# WP_Query search for diffrence RANGES of Prices

Tags: php, range, wordpress

I want to show Dropdown where show Price Range like this

```
$0 - $999
$1000 - $1999
$2000 - $2999
$3000 - $3999
```

and don't display a option that doesn't have any posts in that price range

Comment: What did you try? See [ask]!

Comment: "I want to show Dropdown where show Price Range like this" Show us then ;-) Seriously you have to me more specific about your actual problem and what you have tried.